# Named routes not resolving in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set up a resource in `routes.rb`:

```
map.resource :papers
```

which is reflected in the output of `rake routes`:

```
 new_papers GET    /papers/new(.:format)                     {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"new"}
edit_papers GET    /papers/edit(.:format)                    {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"edit"}
     papers GET    /papers(.:format)                         {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"show"}
            PUT    /papers(.:format)                         {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"update"}
            DELETE /papers(.:format)                         {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"destroy"}
            POST   /papers(.:format)                         {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"create"}
```

The problem arises when I attempt to redirect to a named route within a controller action. This is an excerpt from the `create` action for the Paper resource. It should redirect the user to the `show` action of the `paper` controller on a successful save.

```
if @paper.save
  redirect_to @paper
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

The exception that arises is: `undefined method 'paper_url'`, suggesting that the controller cannot see the named route. These helper methods will work in views, however.

As far as I can tell, this is the same way a Rails scaffold sets up a resource, so I can't find what's wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be map.resource**s** :papers

I could only get the error my copying out my route so I figured it must be a typo.

Comment: meaning there needs to be an s at the end of map.resource

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake

The scaffold for paper model will look like this:

```
   papers GET    /papers(.:format)                  {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"index"}
           POST   /papers(.:format)                  {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"create"}
 new_paper GET    /papers/new(.:format)              {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"new"}
edit_paper GET    /papers/:id/edit(.:format)         {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"edit"}
     paper GET    /papers/:id(.:format)              {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"show"}
           PUT    /papers/:id(.:format)              {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"update"}
           DELETE /papers/:id(.:format)              {:controller=>"papers", :action=>"destroy"}
```

have a look especially for the show method:

```
paper GET    /papers/:id(.:format)
```

instead of yours:

```
 papers GET    /papers(.:format)
```